# health check for Python script inside a container

Tags: python, docker, containers, health-check

I have a python script running inside a container, sometime it fails.
I would like to know if it is possible to create a healthcheck for that script and in case of failure delete this container and raise a new one.

Comment: I would suggest looking at watch dog scripts, https://github.com/buanet/docker.watchdog . In addition is you script failing stopping the container?

Comment: No , if the script fails it does not stop the container.

Comment: My suggestion would be to make the script stop the container and then monitor the container. It should be possible to edit the script to exit in the failure condition, if you are having trouble with this consider adding a code snippet of your script.

Comment: Are you using their provided dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I am using their provided dockerfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234747/discussion-between-user1010-and-yanir).

Comment: Are you running the container in kubernetes?

Comment: No , I am running the container in docker.

Comment: Sent all the information in the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually modified this part

```
if not self.setOutputSyslogHandler:
       syslogger.addHandler(syslog)
       self.setOutputSyslogHandler = True
```

I modified it to remove the handler and add it every time it uses it again.

```
syslogger.addHandler(syslog)
for msg in decrypted_file.splitlines():
                if msg != '':
                    try:
                        syslogger.info(msg)
                    except:
                        self.logger.error('Error sending log file to syslog server %s on port %s via protocol %s', self.config.SYSLOG_ADDRESS, self.config.SYSLOG_PORT, self.config.SYSLOG_PROTO)
                        self.running = False
                        sys.exit(1)
while syslogger.hasHandlers():
      syslogger.removeHandler(syslogger.handlers[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest editing the log downloader to ensure it exists,

```
... # line 255 ( https://github.com/imperva/incapsula-logs-downloader/blob/master/script/LogsDownloader.py )

    """
    Saves the decrypted file content to a log file in the filesystem
    """
    def handle_log_decrypted_content(self, filename, decrypted_file):
        decrypted_file = decrypted_file.decode('utf-8')

        if self.config.SYSLOG_ENABLE == 'YES':
            syslogger = logging.getLogger("syslog")
            syslogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

            if self.config.SYSLOG_PROTO == 'TCP':
                self.logger.info('Syslog enabled, using TCP')
                syslog = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(self.config.SYSLOG_ADDRESS, int(self.config.SYSLOG_PORT)), socktype=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            else:
                self.logger.info('Syslog enabled, using UDP')
                syslog = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(self.config.SYSLOG_ADDRESS, int(self.config.SYSLOG_PORT)))
            
            ### Add by Maytee Sittipornchaisakul
            if not self.setOutputSyslogHandler:
                syslogger.addHandler(syslog)
                self.setOutputSyslogHandler = True                
            
            for msg in decrypted_file.splitlines():
                if msg != '':
                    try:
                        syslogger.info(msg)
                    except:
                        self.logger.error('Error sending log file to syslog server %s on port %s via protocol %s', self.config.SYSLOG_ADDRESS, self.config.SYSLOG_PORT, self.config.SYSLOG_PROTO)
                        self.running = False
                        sys.exit(1)

        if self.config.SAVE_LOCALLY == "YES":
            local_file = open(self.config.PROCESS_DIR + filename, "a+")
            local_file.writelines(decrypted_file)

...
```

This will hopefully cause the script to exit when syslog errors, you can then handle the exited container with some kind of watchdog such as the --restart option discussed in chat.

Comment: The same problem keeps occurring, with the same error, it does not seem to throw an exception.